# Extract uploaded email metadata into SPO columns: feasible with SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, metadata, sharepoint-framework

I am attempting to develop a solution to provide the following functionality:

- When an email file (.msg) is uploaded to a SharePoint Online folder
  configured for emails, the email metadata (to, from, subject, etc.)
  is automatically extracted and saved into corresponding columns.

There are third-party products for this, but if possible my client wants to avoid the ongoing costs and implement their own solution.

**My question is**: would it be feasible to do this with a client-side Javascript add-in created with the SharePoint Framework?

The theory is if the script included an email parser* to extract metadata from the email header, then this could be saved into columns via a CRUD operation provided by SPFx. This would be fired via an eventlistener or Workflow attached to the folder that the emails are uploaded to.

Before I go too far down the SPFx road, could someone please confirm if this is a realistic approach?

(*such as this one: https://github.com/ykarpovich/msg.reader)

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting situation :)

I reckon you can use a combination of Microsoft Flow (triggered when a new item is uploaded) + Azure Function (A call from Flow to execute an azure function that would call a powershell script) + Powershell script (Run a powershell script to extract the msg file details) => update back the SP site with the extracted details.

The Azure function is the stapler here, since I am not aware of a direct possibility to execute a PS script.